# Return types in Java - long to int casting - IntelliJ complains?

Tags: java, casting, intellij-idea, return-value

So I have this method:

[image]

So why is IntelliJ warning me that return x is not allowed there, but it is ok just above? The id of class ProjectElement is also of type long.

**Please do not answer the question without actually reading it. :)**

Comment: In future *please* provide code as text rather than (or possibly as well as) images. The fact that we have to manually type in your code in order to quote it in an answer is annoying.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, my goal was to show that IntelliJ is warning me for a particular return statement but not for the other one, even they are both of type "long".

Comment: Sure (even though they're not) - but there's no reason you couldn't have *described* that but included the code as text, or included it as text *and* a screenshot if necessary.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are right, they are not :) My bad. Thanks anyway. I will pay attention and include text always as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume by "it is ok just above" you refer to is:

```
return (p1.getId().compareTo(p2.getId());
```

That's not returning the ID (which is a `Long`) - it's returning the result of the `compareTo` method, which is an `int`. (See the [`Long.compareTo(Long)` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Long%29).)

There's no implicit conversion from `long` to `int`, which is why your statement of `return x;` is invalid.

It seems to me that *all* you need to do is change the declaration of `x` to be `int` instead of `long` - you're only populating it from the result of a `compareTo` call, after all:

```
// Removed extraneous brackets as well...
int x = p1.getCustomerUnit().getId().compareTo(p2.getCustomerUnit().getId());
if (x == 0) {
    return p1.getId().compareTo(p2.getId());
}
return x;
```

It's important to distinguish between the type of the ID, and the type of the result of a comparison between IDs.

Comment: I mean the IDEA does not warn me for the row: return(p1.getId()... ) but for the row below it does.. But they both return long values?

Comment: @KorayTugay: No, they're not. Please read my answer carefully (especially if you're complaining about people not reading your question carefully) - the return type of the `compareTo` method is `int`, not `long`.

Answer (score 5):

Error is because, `compare()` method declares to return `int`, you are returning `long`.

`ProjectElement`'s Id variable is type of Long, and `Long`'s [`compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare%28long,%20long%29) method return `int`.

`(p1.getId().compareTo(p2.getId())` returning int, since `Id` is type of `Long`, and Long's [`compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare%28long,%20long%29) method return int

Comment: No problem my friend.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for complaining is that returning a `long` for an `int` would cause truncation, you're throwing away half the bits!

If you really must do this, cast it: `return (int)x;` and be prepared for the consequences :-)

Cheers,